# Fancybox - setting next/previous URL's?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, lightbox

I have a gallery which uses Fancybox to load an iFrame inside the lightbox depending on what parameters are passed through the URL. Everything works fine on the normal gallery pages (as all the images are on the page for fancybox to load in).

My problem is that in another section of the site I have an area which shows the last 3 images added to a number of galleries, which when clicked open up a fancybox in the same fashion as the normal gallery pages, but the next/previous only cycles through these 3 latest images, not all the images in the gallery.

The only solution I can think of at the moment would involve adding hidden links for fancybox to pick up, but I feel this could get messy and hopefully there is a nicer way.

So, is there a way of setting the next/previous URL's?
Or another solution to this issue that someone has used/can think of?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, the "solution" I have had to use is to output numerous empty anchor tags on the page for each gallery on the page.

So gallery 1 looks something like:

```
<a href="/foo/large/bar1.jpg" rel="gallery1">
  <img src="/foo/thumbs/bar1.jpg" alt="foo bar" />
</a>
<a href="/foo/large/bar2.jpg" rel="gallery1">
  <img src="/foo/thumbs/bar2.jpg" alt="foo bar" />
</a>
<a href="/foo/large/bar3.jpg" rel="gallery1">
  <img src="/foo/thumbs/bar3.jpg" alt="foo bar" />
</a>
<a href="/foo/large/bar4.jpg" rel="gallery1"></a>
<a href="/foo/large/bar5.jpg" rel="gallery1"></a>
<a href="/foo/large/bar6.jpg" rel="gallery1"></a>
...
```

It makes the code very messy (often on one page there are hundreds of empty links), but nothing changes on the page, and it doesn't seem to slow the page down much (if at all), so I guess it's only me who will really care that much about the empty anchors being there in the markup. IMO it's not an ideal solution, but it works.

Again, if someone has a cleaner/nicer solution to this problem, please do share the answer as I for one would be very interested!